# f# type attribute access

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-3.0

Is there any way one can access the type attribute by using it's name represented in a `string`. Something along the lines of:

```
type B = {FirstName:string; LastName:string} 
let b = { FirstName="Bob"; LastName="Smith" }  
b.``"FirstName"``
```

The reason being that I want to access the type dynamically based on the `xml` based map.

Comment: You can use reflection for that, but you'll lose the strong typing protection, because, obviously, the compiler can't make sure that the types are correct when it doesn't know what they are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is something you can do via reflection. In addition to the general .NET reflection API, F# comes with a small reflection library, `Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection`, that provides some utility functions for constructing and decomposing basic F# types like records.

You can get `PropertyInfos` of all the record fields using:

```
FSharpType.GetRecordFields(typeof<B>)
```

Then you can decompose a record into an array of values and put them back into a record like this:

```
let fields = FSharpValue.GetRecordFields(b)
let b' = FSharpValue.MakeRecord(typeof<B>, fields) :?> B
```

You can build your own persistence library on top of that, but this is for the most part a solved problem. I think Json.NET should handle serializing records out of the box now, for sure there's an xml equivalent as well.

F# also offers a distinct alternative in the form of type providers. If you want your xmls to "drive" how your types look - particularly if you're accessing external sources that communicate through xml - you may want to look into [`FSharp.Data` and `XmlProvider`](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/XmlProvider.html). They give a very similar vibe to what you're doing in your example - you point the type provider to an xml sample and it generates a type corresponding to the xml's structure during the compilation. So you can just use the xml node names as regular field names in F# code, in a statically typed fashion.

Type providers are good for scripting and exploratory programming, since they save you time having to declare and update type definitions. But when building a more long-lasting application, you may find it desirable to use explicitly defined types as the representation.

Comment: Perfect! thanks both for the comments and explanations.